# What are the required permssions for Azure DevOps to execute Get-AzureADServicePrincipal cmdlet?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-service-principal

I am deploying Azure Function based application using Azure DevOps pipeline, as part of deployment the required infrastructure is also provisioned (using ARM templates).  The Azure function needs to access Microsoft Graph & SharePoint REST API's, to achieve this following steps are taken:

1. Azure function is created with system assigned identity (MSI).
2. The MSI (identity) is passed to below PowerShell script for enabling access to Graph & SharePoint API.

```
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
 
Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
 
$azureFunctionServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "ObjectId eq '$PrincipalId'"
#Graph service principal
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
$GraphFilesReadWriteAllAppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -in 'Files.ReadWrite.All' -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains 'Application'}
New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -PrincipalId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $GraphFilesReadWriteAllAppRole.Id

$SharePointOnlineServicePrinciple = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString “Office 365 SharePoint”
$SharePointOnlineSitesReadWriteAllAppRole = $SharePointOnlineServicePrinciple.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -in 'Sites.ReadWrite.All' -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains 'Application'}
New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -PrincipalId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $SharePointOnlineServicePrinciple.ObjectId -Id $SharePointOnlineSitesReadWriteAllAppRole.Id
```

The PowerShell script while executing Get-AzureADServicePrincipal command fails due to insufficient privileges, this command is executing under the DevOps's ServiceConnection identity.  The ServiceConnection is assigned with following additional privileges,
[image]

I am unable to figure out what other privileges are required for GetServicePrincipal to succeed, and, also for execution of New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment cmdlet.

**[Update 31st Aug, 2020]**  Thanks to solution by AlleWu, the permission issue related GetServicePrincipal is resolved.  However, the permission issue for the execution of NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment persists in spite of below permission, am i missing some step.  I have additionally made the ServiceConnection object as owner of the ResourceGroup, but this too failed.

[image: Service Connection permissions]

NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment execution error log:

```
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5613075Z ##[debug]+ New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $EcaseServicePrincipal. ...
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5639370Z ##[debug]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5721318Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5744883Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewServ    icePrincipalAppRoleAssignment
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5765560Z ##[debug] 
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5834409Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-08-31T05:24:55.5976760Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\1\s\azure.pipelines\pwsh\provision_service_principle_for_sharepoint_graph.ps1: line 23
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6006045Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6029248Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\4.173.1\azurepowershell.ps1: line 229
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6188575Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\AzurePowerShell_72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62\4.173.1\azurepowershell.ps1: line 225
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6219503Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6243577Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6281986Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6331521Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6497107Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6577566Z ##[debug]Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException: Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment 
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6607345Z ##[debug]Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6683059Z ##[debug]Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6712669Z ##[debug]RequestId: 14e5694e-bfde-404f-a441-4543871b1e56
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6760142Z ##[debug]DateTimeStamp: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 05:24:53 GMT
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6794376Z ##[debug]HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6818439Z ##[debug]HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6842869Z ##[debug]HttpResponseStatus: Completed
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6890342Z ##[debug]
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6915727Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.Configuration.<>c.<.cctor>b__47_0(String methodName, IRestResponse response) in X:\bt\1137570\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V2\AzureAD16.Client\Client\Configuration.cs:line 188
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6947059Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Api.ServicePrincipalApi.NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignmentWithHttpInfo(String tenantId, String objectId, String authorization, String cmdletName, String clientRequestId, String apiVersion, AppRoleAssignment appRoleAssignment) in X:\bt\1137570\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V2\AzureAD16.Client\Api\ServicePrincipalApi.cs:line 4006
2020-08-31T05:24:55.6977721Z ##[debug]   at Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment.ProcessRecord() in X:\bt\1137570\repo\src\dev\PowerShell.V2\AzureAD16.PowerShell\AzureAD16.PowerShell.AutoGen\API\ServicePrincipalApi.cs:line 2019
2020-08-31T05:24:55.7008421Z ##[debug]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2020-08-31T05:24:55.7366976Z ##[error]Error occurred while executing NewServicePrincipalAppRoleAssignment 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: 14e5694e-bfde-404f-a441-4543871b1e56
DateTimeStamp: Mon, 31 Aug 2020 05:24:53 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
```

**Update 1st Set, 2020:** The alternate solution suggested above worked, below i have updated the script used to provision required permissions,

```
$context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
$graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
$aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken

Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id
 
$webAppServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "ObjectId eq '$PrincipalId'" #$PrincipalId is the ObjectId of the webApp instance
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'"
$GraphFilesReadWriteAllAppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Value -in 'Files.ReadWrite.All' -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains 'Application'}

#It appears that the Azure DevOps's service connection need to have Global Administrator permissions to successfully execute the below statement; which is not recommended, hence, this is implemented calling Graph API 
#New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -PrincipalId $EcaseServicePrincipal.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $GraphFilesReadWriteAllAppRole.Id

$resourceId = $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId
$body = @{
  "principalId"= $webAppServicePrincipal.ObjectId
  "resourceId"= $resourceId
  "appRoleId"= $GraphFilesReadWriteAllAppRole.Id
}

$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/$resourceId/appRoleAssignedTo"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($graphToken)" }  -Method POST -Body $($body | convertto-json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: @AllenWu:  The solution you shared did resolve the permission issue related to execution of GetServicePrincipal.  I am now facing permission issue while executing New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment, i have given following permissions under AD Graph: Application.RW.All, Directory.RW.All; under Msft Graph: Application.RW.All, AppRoleAssignment.RW.All.  What other permission are required for this?

Comment: Directory.RW.All under AAD Graph should be the one you need. Rememeber to click Grant admin consent.

Comment: @AllenWu:  I think the required permissions are already in place, i have updated my query with additional information.

Comment: I'll have a quick test/confirmation and come back once there is any update.

Comment: Please see the **UPDATE** in my answer.

Comment: Hi any updates?

Comment: @AllenWu: Thanks, the alternate solution worked.  I have accepted the solution as answer.

Comment: You edit my answer to add your update. So I reject it and add the update to your post:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` command is calling Azure AD Graph rather than Microsoft Graph.

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
```

So you should give the Azure AD Graph permission:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Found something interesting:

Although I assigned all the AAD Graph application permissions to the service principal, it still shows "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".

So I use another method: assign **Global Administrator** role to this service principal. But it has a delay about 10-15 minutes. Then the service principal can  execute `New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment` successfully.

I also test with **Application Administrator** role but it doesn't work. I think AAD Graph has some changes and won't be maintained. So it's unrecommended to use it.

As a workaround, you can call Microsoft Graph API: [Grant an appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for a service principal in your Powershell script.